# Set Text of Anchor Tag In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I set the text of an anchor tag in javascript? This does not seem to work. I'm using firefox.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.innerHtml = "Remove";
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is `innerHTML`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 8):

Property names are case sensitive in Javascript.

Try

```
link.innerHTML = "Remove";
```

You will need to attach the created element to the document, too. But I assume you're doing that in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 5):

innerHtml should be innerHTML (capitalized 'HTML')

Answer (score 4):

The property name is case sensitive and should be `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this one:

```
link.textContent= "Remove";
```