# Quick Question. JavaScript. I added a link with createElement, but it's invisible

Tags: html, jscript

I tried to add an  element with JScript code, I gave it href and title attributes... but the link is invisible on the page ( if I check through browsers elements, it highlights an empty space which says "a     0x17". What's wrong with it? What should I do, to make it visible?

```
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const b = document.querySelector('body');
    
    a.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole")
    a.setAttribute("title", "Blah-blah");
    b.appendChild(a);
```

if I write a.textContent("...") it's visible, but it's just a text, not a link. When I gave it href attribute, it became invisible.

Comment: Is it JavaScript or JScript? Your title says one but the body and tags say the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Text of Anchor Tag In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496280/set-text-of-anchor-tag-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a link using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772774/how-do-i-create-a-link-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x17` is the size of the element in the window. What happened here is your link element does not have content (between `<a></a>` tags.  It needs any content to be displayed :

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
const b = document.querySelector('body');
a.innerHTML = 'Link content';
a.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole")
a.setAttribute("title", "Blah-blah");
b.appendChild(a);
```